# SQL Write History of Last one week

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can we get below information?

1. SQL Server 2008 R2 write history of Last one week?
2. I want to know the Disk utilization per/hour for last one week.

We want know reason for strange IO increase in one of our PROD servers.

Please let me know if someone can help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this only if you are monitoring this.

You can also check for problems at a certain time, if you see in SQL Server Log waiting to perform IO operation.

I would start by doing all the Glenn Alan Berry scripts. https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2016/06/08/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-june-2016/

You can run a perfmon together with a sqlprofiler and look for the statements that are causing problems (this will give you hardware an query information which you will have to combine)

What I usually get my customers to use is SQL Sentry(SentryOne) this is a montoring tool which has a month free trial. This will show all information you need correlated to queries in an easy to understand GUI. This however is not the only solution, but it is the one I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the writes to SQL Server if you enable auditing on the Database

More info

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx